# How to access sys.preferredJre from a script in install4j?

Tags: java, macos, install4j

My application uses authentication through a LDAP server over SSL. This requires installation of certificates in the bundled JRE's keystore. I use a script to do it through Java code and in the process need to find the location of the installed JRE. This script is executed at the end of the installation.

On Windows, it's relatively simple: I just use `context.getInstallationDirectory()` and then add `jre\lib\security\cacerts`.

On Mac OS, however, the JRE is installed in a different location and I would need to use the actual `sys.preferredJre` or the `java.home` property. The problem is that I can't access them from the scripts. The context object doesn't seem to have the corresponding methods. `System.getProperty("java.home")` returns a temporary location where the JRE is probably first unpacked and not the final path. 
`context.getCompilerVariable("sys.preferredJre")` returns null.

As a side note, there doesn't seem to be any logging from inside the scripts. All I get is a brief message about the script succeeding or failing. I had to write to a custom file to get any information.

Can you suggest a way to handle this? Ideally, I would like to do it in OS-independent way and just get the Jre directory.

Thanks in advance

Sasha

Answer (score 0):

After the "Install files" action has run, the `sys.preferredJre` installer variable is set to the directory where the bundled JRE has been installed. You can get this variable by calling

```
context.getVariable("sys.preferredJre")
```

In your question, you use `getCompilerVariable`, which is not correct because it returns values of compiler variables.

Comment: Thank you, Ingo. I just tested it and it worked great.